# How to check if a bit is set in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps, bitflags

How do I check if a particular bit is set on an integer value within a PowerApp? There doesn’t seem to be a built-in operator or function for bit manipulation.

As I do need this for quite few operations, using an external / Custom Connector is probably too *expensive* for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find if a bit `b` of a number `val` is set, you can use an expression like the one below:

```
RoundDown(Mod(val,Power(2,b+1))/Power(2,b),0)
```

An example of this expression is shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Formula

```
Mod(Trunc(Number / (2 ^ Bit)), 2) = 1
```

This expression will be `true` if `Bit` flag (counting from zero) for the value `Number` is set. Otherwise `false`.

### Examples

**32 (00100000)**

`Number` = **32** `Bit` = **0** : `false`
`Number` = **32** `Bit` = **4** : `false`
`Number` = **32** `Bit` = **5** : `true`

**33 (00100001)**

`Number` = **33** `Bit` = **0** : `true`
`Number` = **33** `Bit` = **4** : `false`
`Number` = **33** `Bit` = **5** : `true`

### Reusability

If you are going to use it often in your app, you might want to **[register it as a custom function](https://matthewdevaney.com/power-apps-custom-functions-reusable-code/)** for easier use